# Django Tutorial Constant 404 error urlpattern recognition

Tags: python, django

I have searched endlessly for a solution and I can't seem to find it, even though I know this has been asked before. I am encountering a perpetual 404 error from the django tutorial. It appears to me that the 'urlpatterns' isn't recognizing another option of than admin.

---

```
backend/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', include('meat.urls')),
    path('admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

---

```
backend/meat/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

---

```
backend/meat/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(requests):
    return HttpResponse('Hello Wold')
```

Comment: what is the URL that you have tried?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/test

Comment: have you tried `127.0.0.1:8000/test/` (ends with slash)

Comment: I have, and i still receives the same error. It tells me there is no object 'test/' in the urlpattern

Comment: Can you paste the error log here.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/
Using the URLconf defined in backend.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, test/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Paste the error with you accessing `127.0.0.1:8000/test/`. That error says you are accessing it with `127.0.0.1:8000/test`

Comment: Request URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/'  Using the URLconf defined in backend.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, test/, didn't match any of these. I am unsure why it does not show in the link, perhaps that is the issue, but there are  back slashes on both sides of '/test/'

Answer (score 1):

In order to access views inside the meat app. 
you have included the urls of meat to the **test/** path.

Thus you should use *url /test/*

if you are developing on local host then **localhost:8000/test/**

NB: I have tested this right now [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raCDe.png)

PS: try changing the path of admin site to `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I find it very interesting it runs on your localhost but not on mine. Even when I tried your suggested url sequence. I also change the path as per your suggestion, still to no success.

Comment: @ethor11 if you don't mind can you comment what was the issue that you have faced

Comment: It ended up working after saving the files i was working in, and then running the 'python manage.py migrate' command.